# Concealing the code for `braket` package for LaTeX with vimtex + `tex-conceal`

Tags: syntax-highlighting, conceal, plugin-vimtex

I am using `vimtex` with `latexmk` and using `conceal` setting provided by `vim` and extending it with an additional plug-in : [`KeitaNakamura/tex-conceal.vim`](https://github.com/KeitaNakamura/tex-conceal.vim). Additionally, I use a package `braket` to encode `\langle`, `\rangle` and `|` nicely.

The `braket` package comes with commands which are used like :

1. `\bra{A}` ( it will print into pdf as `<A|` and I want to conceal in my tex file so that it appears like : `<A|`)
2. `\ket{A}` ( it will print into pdf as `|A>` and I want to conceal in my tex file so that it appears like : `|A>`)
3. `\bracket{A|B}` ( it will print into pdf as `<A|B>` and I want to conceal in my tex file so that it appears like : `<A|B>`)

My aim is to use conceal feature of `vim` on the commands that come with the `braket` package which is not available by default or by the plug-in I am using.

Short of asking the developer of the plug-in to include support for `braket` package is there any other method by which I can achieve this? Writing some custom code or using some other plugin?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the following:

```
" ~/.vim/after/syntax/tex.vim
syntax match texMathSymbol /\\bra{\%([^}]*}\)\@=/ conceal cchar=<
syntax match texMathSymbol /\%(\\bra{[^}]*\)\@<=}/ conceal cchar=|
syntax match texMathSymbol /\\ket{\%([^}]*}\)\@=/ conceal cchar=|
syntax match texMathSymbol /\%(\\ket{[^}]*\)\@<=}/ conceal cchar=>
syntax match texMathSymbol /\\braket{\%([^}]*}\)\@=/ conceal cchar=<
syntax match texMathSymbol /\%(\\braket{[^}]*\)\@<=}/ conceal cchar=>
```

If you want to keep the highlight group when not concealing, you’ll need to get the highlight group for commands like `\langle` (`texStatement`, I believe) and replace `bra`, `ket`, and `braket` with it.

---

For the curious, the weapons of choice here are

- `\%(\)` non-capturing groups (they're slightly more performant)
- `\@=` matches the preceding atom with zero-width *and doesn't consume the match*<sup>1</sup>
- `\@<=` matches the preceding atom with zero-width only if what follows also matches *and doesn't consume the match*<sup>1</sup>

1. We need this "non-consuming" behavior—`\zs` and `\ze` could be used to build the right patterns, but because we are creating overlaps we need to not consume anything. `\zs` and `\ze` will consume the matches they make which prevents vim's syntax engine from examining that text again.

We can't use `region` because we need two different conceal characters (one on each end of the region). This is not supported natively, so workarounds like double-matches are required.

Comment: Sorry but this didn't work for me!

Comment: This failed as well. Actually the command from `braket` package is `\bra{%}` with some expression in place of `%` and in compiled file it is displayed as : `<%|`. I am having concealing feature with `langle` whether I use this command or not and if I use the same command for `\bra{}` this doesn't work. Here's what I tried : `syntax match braket /\\bra/ conceal cchar=<` and a few variations (I didn't put any braces after`bra` in this command and hence didn't do the same in my tex file as well.)

Comment: @Nitin please edit your question to include this—it’s hard to answer a question that is underspecified, and I’m still not sure I follow. Please given some example usages and how you would like them to appear on screen.

Comment: @Nitin please try the update

Comment: Sorry, this didn't work either. Maybe I am doing something wrong. If you can kindly suggest some reference for this then I will read and try to do something. I tried `:h syntax` and it did give me an idea but not sufficient, perhaps. Thanks a lot for trying so many times. :)

Comment: This worked for me with your test cases. Can you explain “didnt work”? @Nitin